# Figure out type of timestamp

Tags: date, time, timestamp

I've occured a strange time-format, and i can't figure out how to convert it to a readable format.

A couple of timestamps from today are

```
32400683 (this morning)
41891077
56517540
57390993
58728120 (this afternoon)
```

Comment: err are those in chronological order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like milliseconds starting from midnight.

Divide by 1000 to get seconds, by 60 to get minutes (60,000), and 60 again to get hours (3,600,000).

That gives you:

```
9.0  => 09:00 (this morning)
11.6 => 11:36
15.7 => 15:42
15.9 => 15:54
16.3 => 16:18 (this afternoon)
```

Comment: Indeed it does: 32400683 -> 9.00 hrs